# Write to file descriptor of socket from bash child process in Node.js

Tags: node.js, shell, sockets, tcp, file-descriptor

I have this:

```
const net = require('net');
const cp = require('child_process');

const server = net.createServer(s => {

  const bash = cp.spawn('bash');

  s.on('data', d => {
     bash.stdin.write(`
      exec ${String(d)};
      echo 'write to socket s here';  // write to s here
    `);
  });


  bash.stdout.pipe(s, {end:false});
  bash.stderr.pipe(s, {end:false});


});

server.listen(4004);
```

does anyone know how I can write to socket s from the bash process? I assume I have to pass the file descriptor number down to bash somehow? How to get file descriptor of socket? I console logged the socket properties and there was not file descriptor that I could see.

something like this:

```
const fd = s.fd;

const bash = cp.spawn('bash', [], {
   env: Object.assign({}, process.env, {
       socketfd: fd
    })
});
```

and then

```
bash.stdin.write(`
    exec ${String(d)};
    echo "test" >&"$socketfd"
`)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to get the file descriptor of the socket:

```
const net = require('net');
const cp = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = net.createServer(s => {

  const fd = s._handle.fd;  // file descriptor

  const bash = cp.spawn('bash', [], {
    env: Object.assign({}, process.env, {
      socket_fd: fd
    })
  });



  s.setEncoding('utf8');

  s.on('data', d => {

    if(String(d).trim() === '∆∆∆'){
      bash.stdout.write('\n$$$');
      return;
    }

    d = String(d);

     bash.stdin.write(`
         set +e;

         ${d}
         echo "file descriptor: $socket_fd"
         echo "∆∆∆\n" >&$socket_fd

     `);
  });


  bash.stdout.pipe(s, {end:false});
  bash.stderr.pipe(s, {end:false});


});

server.listen(4004);
```

**but when I connect to this with  nc localhost 4004, and run simple echo command, I get this:**

> ```
> echo foo
> foo
> file descriptor: 22
> bash: line 8: 1: Bad file descriptor
> ```

child procs are supposed to inherit the file descriptors from the parent proc so I don't see why it would be a "bad file descriptor"??